# Hide my API via reverse proxy. How do I have a resty api that returns and hide a url behind a reverse proxy

Tags: http, nginx, backend, port, reverse-proxy

Hide my API via reverse proxy. How do I have a resty api that returns and hide a url behind a reverse proxy

Hello I want for example to mirror github.com/mirrorme
(in practice I want to miror an api resty with my api key but I want to hide it)

so what I want is lets say I

```
localhost:80/?mirror=https://github.com/?key=topsecret_apikey&video=1441
```

so when I call Example 1
I want to get in return this text (from the HTTP-get request)

```
What I want when calling our RESTY (in example 1)
localhost:80/reversedUrl/?id=lkjdflkjgdfjlk
```

and when I call the URL we got in return I can give it to a someone I dont trust with my api key and will have access to this data. How do I reverse proxy / tunnel.
everything needs manual configuation. like NGINX.

I dont even mind having this RESTY hosted in NODEJS or even PYTHON. I just really want this to work. (and it need to work under SSL)

Comment: *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
I tried https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/

Comment: Bump still relecent please help :(